# Get first element in Grails list

Tags: list, grails, select

How can I get the first element in Grails list of object return from command .list(), but not use Java method. I means that do we have any option to select the top element when call .list(), similar to the SQL query SELECT TOP FROM .

I don't like using this:

```
List domains = Domain.list()
return domains.get(0)
```

Becayse it causes memory resources so much.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A quick way is to use the max parameter with `list`

```
Domain.list([max:1])
```

Or you could use a Criteria query I believe:

```
def domainCriteria = Domain.createCriteria()
def firstDomain = domainCriteria.list{
    maxResults( 1 )
    order( 'id', 'asc' )
}[0]
```

Comment: maybe try .get{ maxResults(1) ... }, without [0]?

Comment: Wouldn't that get you a list containing one item, rather than the single item itself?

Comment: it returns the item, not a list

Comment: Sorry about that, I mis-read your comment, and thought you still were using `list` :-/

Comment: If you stick `uniqueResult = true` in the criteria query, it'll return the object or null instead of a list.  If more than one object is matched, it throws an exception.

Answer (score 2):

As of [Grails 2.1.1](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8821), [`first()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/first.html) and [`last()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/last.html) methods have been added.

```
def firstResult = Domain.first()
```

and

```
def lastResult = Domain.last()
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it is with `find`, which returns the first result, or null if the table is empty.

```
User.find("from User")
```

If you want more than one, you can also use `findAll` with a max parameter

```
User.findAll("from User", [max: 10])
```

If you truly want just any object from the table, then `list` is probably your best bet, but most of the time, with these kinds of queries, you want to constrain it a bit more than that and going to HQL can make that very easy.